# HTML Email - Outlook.com is moving CSS styling from one DOM element to another

Tags: html, css, email, outlook

I know the title of this post sounds strange, but it's exactly what's happening. While testing an email template with Email and Acid and Litmus I found that Outlook.com, in all browsers, was migrating styling from one DOM element to another. I thought at first it was an unescaped tag or other common issue with email, but that wasn't the case. I also thought it could be the button markup, which was pulled from Litmus's own [Bullet Proof Buttons](https://litmus.com/blog/a-guide-to-bulletproof-buttons-in-email-design) post. But after trying all four options, plus others I found online, it didn't make a difference.

To discreetly troubleshoot this I crafted an email template with only the bare minimum needed to reproduce the what's happening.

Email Template: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/bOQmzz

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta content="width=device-width" name="viewport">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Page Title</title>
</head>
<body>

<!-- BUTTON -->
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td style="padding: 10px;">
                <a style="background-color: #800080; border: 25px solid #EB7035;" href="#" >Button Label</a>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>

<!-- TEXT -->
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td style="padding: 50px;">
                <p>Hello World</p>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>

</body>
</html>
```

I sent a test email from Litmus to an Outlook.com account I have access to and pulled the actual markup it's generating. Here it is.

```
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td style="padding:10px">Button Label</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td style="background-color:#800080; border:25px solid #EB7035; padding:50px">
                <p>Hello World</p>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

As you can see it's taking the styling from TD > A and applying it to the following TD. In the original email template I had, this happened multiple times throughout. See the examples below

**Original Template: Each blue sections is broken**
[image: Original Email Template]

**Testing Template: Outlook.com in multiple browsers**
[image: Outlook.com in multiple browsers]

**Testing Template: Examples of other email clients**
[image: Examples of other email clients]

This feels more like an Outlooks.com bug than an Outlook.com quirk. Can anyone explain what's happening and suggest ways to resolve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After writing this all up I realized it was also stripping the A tag. And that this was probably because it wasn't a resolvable URL. In the original template I had ESP codes {campaign-ID...etc} and it probably wasn't resolving those either. So it just stripped them for security reasons, cool. But then for some reason, it takes the styling of that A link, strips it, and applies it to an element further down in the DOM. WTF were they thinking!

Hope this saves someone else the trouble from having to go down the same rabbit hole.

tl;dr This is only an issue when testing links with unresolvable URLs as outlook removes them for security reasons, but then fumbles and applies the styling on the removed A link to another DOM element.

Comment: Email can be difficult. Outlook makes it harder.